# How to setup the passwords-less authentication between two different accounts

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, system-administration, password-less

Can we setup a password less authentication between two different uses in two machine.

Eg: Computer A has user A,Computer B has user B.
Can we setup passwords ssh that User A from Computer A to log into computer B using his User account(A).

Thank you!!

Comment: Googling your question _How to setup the passwords-less authentication between two different accounts_ I found a hundred of great tutorials. Why do you prefer to ask and wait for the answer **instead doing a minimal research**?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, can you set up `ssh-keys` to allow *user A* and *user B* to log into to two different computers *A & B* without providing a password? Sure, but *user A* can't log into *user B*'s account via ssh any more than *user A* can log into *user B*'s account on a local machine. (directory ownerships are different for the `$HOME`, etc.. That's what `su` is for).

To create a password less login, let's take *user A* and *computer A* who has an account on *computer B* and would like to `ssh hostnameB` and login without providing a password.

**(1)** user A creates a *public_key* and *private_key* on *computer A* with `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa` (for an `ecdsa` encryption key. `dsa` keys are no longer supported due to insecurity in the current openssh). When `ssh-keygen` is run it will create two files (by default in `$HOME/.ssh`). The keys are `id_edcsa` (the private key) and `id_ecdsa.pub` (the public key).

**(2)** for *user A* to login to *computer B* without a password, he must first transfer his *public_key* to *computer B* and add it to his `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on *computer B*. e.g. from *computer A*:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ecdsa  # generate key-pair
$ cd ~/.ssh            # verify private and public keys created
$ rsync -a id_ecdsa.pub hostnameB:~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub.hostA
  password: enter pw

$ ssh hostnameB
  password: enter pw
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ cat id_dsa.pub.hostA >> authorized_keys  # permissions must be 0600
$ exit                # exit hostnameB
```

**note:** above you could `rsync` the public_key directory to the *computer B* `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file if you are sure one does NOT already exist to save time a completely skip the last step copying the transferred file into it above. e.g.

```
$ rsync -a id_ecdsa.pub hostnameB:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(you may have to check permissions on *computer B* afterwards)

Now for the test, *user A* should no longer need a password to long into *computer B*. From *computer A*:

```
$ ssh hostnameB
$ welcome to hostnameB>
```

Now you simply repeat the process of creating key-pairs for each user and transferring the *public_key* to the host you want to access w/o a password and add the *public_key* to the *authorized_keys* file. (note: you can just copy the same *private_key* to everyone's `~/.ssh` directory and add the same *public_key* to everyone's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, but that sort of defeats the purpose of having separate keys). **note:** each `authorized_keys` file must be owned by the user owning the `$HOME/.ssh` directory and the file permissions must be `0600` (`-rw-------`) or `sshd` will not allow a connection.

That's all there is to it (you can check in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to insure the name of `authorized_keys` file has not been changed to something else.

Give it a try and let me know if you have questions. I done it hundreds of times -- no issues as long as your follow those rules.

Comment: Glad it helps, it is pretty simple once you have done it a time or two, but figuring it out for the first time can be difficult (especially given the number of poorly written examples out on the web)