# Shell script to copy one directory from one server to another without asking for password

Tags: shell, unix

I want to write a shell script and put it in a cron. This shell script will copy one particular directory from my server to another server everyday once. So, I don't want it to prompt for passwords. Is there something that I can add in my script so that it wont ask for passwords everyday?

Comment: You will want to see [**How to setup the passwords-less authentication between two different accounts**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171227/how-to-setup-the-passwords-less-authentication-between-two-different-accounts/36172337?s=1|0.4401#36172337) and then use `rsync` within your `cron` script to backup files from host1 to host2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a password less SSH Login in your Unix Boxes

Below link describe how to set password less SSH login

http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

you can use FTP or NDM to transfer the Files

In this way you can achieve your requirement.

Comment: Can I use rsync? because I need this script to run everyday, so instead of copying again and again, It will just update. If this is possible then explain how??

Comment: I have never used rsync in my case we get fresh new files daily so we copy daily

Comment: Using this script I am able to achieve what I mentioned earlier : 
com="sshpass -p Password0 scp arul@172.25.184.93:/home/arul/test.sh ."
eval $com

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Using the below script, I am able to achieve what I mentioned :

**#!/bin/bash
com="sshpass -p Password0 scp arul@172.25.184.93:/home/arul/test.sh ."
eval $com**

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSA key option also for this. Using RSA key you can authorized your second server in first server. This is one time operation.

```
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [Your 2nd server IP]
```

Example:-

```
[root@vasmon home]#  ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'", and check in:

.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
[root@vasmon home]#
```