# How to use ssh to execute actions that are keyboard interactive by supplying static text

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, openssh

I'm writing a shell script to connect to a Linux based remote machine using `ssh`

After successfully logging in to the remote machine I'm able to execute Linux commands, now the real problem I'm facing is when trying to run the same script for another remote machine which will ask for a local authentication(`username` and `password`) upon `ssh` login to proceed further.

Can someone guide me on how to fill the first line with my `username` and immediately do a carriage return and perform similar action for `password`.

I've tried the below code `connect.sh`

```
sshpass -p <remote-passwd> ssh root@<remote-ip> 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

`test.sh` contain

```
ls
pwd
```

If I run `connect.sh` script it executes perfectly without asking for remote machine password. It also executes `ls` and `pwd`

Can I actually replace `ls` and `pwd` with my `username` and `password` to achieve what I'm trying to do??

Also, Am I looking on something which is not possible?? (I have seen a similar code in VB.NET which is solving my purpose but it is not a robust code and I really don't have any idea on `VB scripts`)

> Update: I'm able to login to remote machine non interactively, but the remote machine environment immediately asks for a local authentication which again requires keyboard interaction, I'm looking for achieving this authentication non interactively

Comment: logging in automatically over SSH is indeed possible, Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script

Comment: See also [**write a shell script to ssh to a remote machine and execute commands**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands).For details on setting up *passwordless* access, see: [**How to setup the passwords-less authentication between two different accounts**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171227/how-to-setup-the-passwords-less-authentication-between-two-different-accounts/36172337?s=1|0.4287#36172337).

Comment: @bdvll I'm okay with this part of the problem, my problem is after achieving this...

Comment: @prince Ok, so what exactly is it that you are having issues with? you could use the 'expect' syntax to add the pass and username passing to your bashcript and then run your commands.

Comment: @bdvll I'll test with that once, and post the update. Thanks!

Comment: You should configure public key authentication so you don't have to type a username and password.

Comment: @Barmar, please see update on my question. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to control interactive programs, take a look at `Expect`.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, you should configure a public key on the server so you don't have to supply a password.  This is more secure and will solve your problem more directly.

You may also want to look into orchestration frameworks, rather than implementing this all yourself.  If you're doing small things, [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) is a good option.  If this looks like it'll become something much larger, you should look into something like [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro.html), which can also additionally handle system configuration and a million other things, but requires very little setup to get started with.

Comment: Thanks @Xiong, will check on the inputs given by you. Thanks.